# Can we Traverse on another page when executing foreach loop?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is Table on the page, I do need to retrieve information row by row. That is handle by for-each. Execution on same page for retrieving information is working fine.

[image]
But, Can we handle Detail page of particular Row ? Here "Test 1" has its own detail page. There are some operation which need to handle on detail page. How can we manage it and get back to actual execution.

As of now I am dealing it with for-each loop, and getting StaleElementReferenceException which is correct as webElement lost its actual `ListElement<WebElement>`

```
List<WebElement> findList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='*****']));

    for (WebElement webElement : findList) {
     ...
    //detail page is access by clicking webElement
    webElement.click();

    findList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='*****']));
    }
```

If there is any way, Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You want to click on Test1 like and then extract some data ? After that coming back to original page (which have Test1, Test2,..) and click on Test2 and do the same thing ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes.

Comment: I see two list in your code `findDevicesList` and `findList ` , which list contains test1 , test2 ,web element ?

Comment: Can you share the XPATH also , by which you are trying to retrieve all the hyperlinks ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Please refer my updated question. Added code for detail page access.

Comment: xpath `//a[@class='*****']` is required , because you are getting stale element reference , so in a loop if you just make your xpath dynamic with increment value of i , such as  `//a[class=''][i]` , may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
List<WebElement> findList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='*****']));
for(int i = 1 ; i<=findList.size() ; i++){

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='***'])[" + i + "]")).click();
   // extract some data from next page which is invoked by clicking on Test1 hyperlink.
}
```

in this way every time you are looking for `//a[@class='***'][i]` web element i , starting from 1 and till the end point.

P.S : You need to check this in devtool `//a[@class='***'][1]`, whether it indicates the **Test1** hyperlink or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me try same.

Comment: Logic Works. Thanks. I have updated answer for required changes in your solution. Changes: 1) <= to  2) Specific Syntax of Xpath with round brackets  ( ) on parent node before assign it to i.

Comment: `//a[@class='***'][i]` is this works for you ? Is it not to be `(//a[@class='***'])[i]`?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Check my edits. round brackets are there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to collect urls to detail pages of all and then open them.

Comment: It is not solution. There is no need of detail page URL. By clicking element it can open detail page. Simple !

Comment: Can you clarify what lost it’s actual List<WebElement> means. Maybe share your code and html

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios i can think of :

1. Clicking the link e.g. Test1 opens a new tab :

   - In this case you can just switch to new tab inside your loop , finish your operation on this tab and finally close the second tab / switch to first tab before continuing with your next iteartion. This should also not cause StaleElementException.
2. Clicking the link e.g. Test1 redirects to some other url in same tab :

   - For each iteration of loop, click on target link , perform some    operation on new page.Before you continue with next iteration ,    Navigate to page containing your table again and lookup all the row    elements again. Now , for next iteration you won't get    StaleElementException. You will want to use the for loop so that you    can maintain the index outside instead of a foreach variant.

> findList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='*****']))

I would recommend the first option since that would be more clean and you can perform a shift + click on your link e.g. Test1 to force it open in a new tab instead of redirecting in same page. You can perform a shift + click using "**Actions api**" available in Selenium.

Comment: Yes 1st scenario is correct, But Unfortunately my application do not maintain session for New Tab, It creates New session of each New Tab and I need to login if I open New tab. So I need to work on same tab. Regarding your second scenario, I do again retrieve findList values before loop finish, But still its throws error.

Comment: `int rowCount = findList.Length; for(int i=0;i<rowCount;i++){ //do something...refresh list agin }` ...Try using this variation of for loop.